# Type of object created by ListCollectionView.AddNew

Tags: wpf, listcollectionview

How does `ListCollectionView.AddNew` determine the type of object it creates, and how could one affect it?

I have a hierarchy of a few types (`Base`, `DerivedA`, and `DerivedB`), and currently my WPF Toolkit `DataGrid` creates `DerivedA` objects (why, I don't know -- probably because almost all the data in the grid is of that type), but I'd like it to create `DerivedB` objects instead.

**Update**: I've tried deriving a new class from `ListCollectionView` and implementing a new `AddNew` method for it, and now I'm almost there: the only remaining problem is that after adding a new item, a new new item placeholder isn't added, so I can only add one item. My current approach looks somewhat like this:

```
public class CustomView : ListCollectionView, IEditableCollectionView
{
    public CustomView(System.Collections.IList list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    object IEditableCollectionView.AddNew()
    {
        DerivedB obj = new DerivedB();
        InternalList.Add(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stale questions deserve fresh answers :)

Deriving a class from `ListCollectionView` is the path I took to control the objects being added by `AddNew` as well, but after browsing through the source of `ListCollectionView` to find out what it does internally, I found that the safest way to redefine `AddNew` (it's not technically an override) is to use `ListCollectionView.AddNewItem` after creating my new object, so your code would look like this:

```
public class CustomView : ListCollectionView, IEditableCollectionView 
{ 
    public CustomView(System.Collections.IList list) 
        : base(list) 
    { 
    } 

    object IEditableCollectionView.AddNew() 
    { 
        DerivedB obj = new DerivedB(); 
        return base.AddNewItem(obj); 
    } 
}
```

This works well because, in addition to having nearly identical implementations otherwise, `ListCollectionView.AddNew()` and `ListCollectionView.AddNewItem(object item)` both call `AddNewCommon(object newItem)`:

```
public object AddNew() 
{ 
    VerifyRefreshNotDeferred();

    if (IsEditingItem)
        CommitEdit();   // implicitly close a previous EditItem

    CommitNew();        // implicitly close a previous AddNew 

    if (!CanAddNew)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.MemberNotAllowedForView, "AddNew")); 

    return AddNewCommon(_itemConstructor.Invoke(null));
}

public object AddNewItem(object newItem)
{
    VerifyRefreshNotDeferred(); 

    if (IsEditingItem) 
        CommitEdit();   // implicitly close a previous EditItem

    CommitNew();        // implicitly close a previous AddNew

    if (!CanAddNewItem) 
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.MemberNotAllowedForView, "AddNewItem"));

    return AddNewCommon(newItem); 
}
```

`AddNewCommon` is where all the real magic happens; firing events, calling `BeginInit` and `BeginEdit` on the new item if supported, and eventually through callbacks on the datagrid, establishing the cell bindings:

```
object AddNewCommon(object newItem)
{
    _newItemIndex = -2; // this is a signal that the next Add event comes from AddNew
    int index = SourceList.Add(newItem); 

    // if the source doesn't raise collection change events, fake one 
    if (!(SourceList is INotifyCollectionChanged)) 
    {
        // the index returned by IList.Add isn't always reliable 
        if (!Object.Equals(newItem, SourceList[index]))
            index = SourceList.IndexOf(newItem);

        BeginAddNew(newItem, index); 
    } 

    Debug.Assert(_newItemIndex != -2 && Object.Equals(newItem, _newItem), "AddNew did not raise expected events"); 

    MoveCurrentTo(newItem);

    ISupportInitialize isi = newItem as ISupportInitialize; 
    if (isi != null)
        isi.BeginInit(); 

    IEditableObject ieo = newItem as IEditableObject;
    if (ieo != null)
        ieo.BeginEdit(); 

    return newItem; 
}
```

Here I've included the source code to my `TypedListCollectionView`, which I use to control the `AddNew` behavior when I don't know what type will be needed at design time:

```
public class TypedListCollectionView : ListCollectionView, IEditableCollectionView
{
    Type AddNewType { get; set; }

    public TypedListCollectionView(System.Collections.IList source, Type addNewType)
        : base(source)
    {
        AddNewType = addNewType;
    }

    object IEditableCollectionView.AddNew()
    {
        object newItem = Activator.CreateInstance(AddNewType);
        return base.AddNewItem(newItem);
    }
}
```

I like this approach since it provides maximum flexibility for cases where `AddNew`'s type may need to be adjusted at runtime from one to another.  It also allows `AddNew` to work for adding the first item in the collection, which is handy when the list source is initially empty, but its underlying type can be determined.

[This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/381dfbbd-1e9a-4a79-8a40-87b4d8767264) discusses an alternative way to force the type used by `AddNew()`.  It uses reflection to set the private `_itemConstructor` property used by `AddNew` to a parameterless constructor of a specified type.  This would be particularly useful when your `ListCollectionView` is coming from a component that's outside of your influence, or you need to add functionality into existing code and you're worried about breaking things (which I never am because I'm a cavalier coder who callously carouses with collections).

Comment: I changed the architecture in my application so this is no longer an issue for me, but your answer does seem plausible based on just looking at it.

Comment: For some reason, I don't seem to have accepted this answer last year.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 4, there is now a new interface [`IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionviewaddnewitem.aspx), implemented by `ListCollectionView`, which possesses a new method `AddNewItem(object)`. You can use it instead of `AddNew()` to control the newly added item.

Comment: Indeed there is, and this answer is equally ok as the one from Erikest I've accepted (by virtue of that answer being older and also mentioning `ListCollectionView.AddNewItem(object)`).

Answer (score 1):

TomiJ,

see if it helps, but isn't the answer ok?

http://www.cnblogs.com/winkingzhang/archive/2008/05/22/1204581.html

Comment: The article (the original one is at <http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/05/20/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-ieditablecollectionview.aspx>) was of some help, as it did set me off looking at `ListCollectionView`.

Comment: I see, i you managed to get the right answer, don't forget to update here.

It's a very interesting question :D

Comment: I'm not quite there yet, as I can only add _one_ new item, but at least the correct AddNew method gets called. I'll have to figure out what else I need to implement to get proper functionality.

Comment: why don't you implement a strategy pattern, are your familiar with the concept?

Comment: Where do you mean I should apply the strategy pattern at? Basically add a new Context class which would contain the Base/DerivedA/DerivedB instances and the collection would then contain these? This is a bit awkward.